# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to write dataframe *0dataframe* to a different excel spreadsheet but getting this error, any ideas?

```
#imports

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#client data, data frame

excel_1 = pd.read_excel (r'path.xlsx')
Odatalocation = (r'path.xlsx')
Odataframe = pd.read_excel(Odatalocation, index_col=0, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "A:C")
print(Odataframe)

#moving client data to new spreadsheet

excel_final = pd.read_excel (r'path.xlsx')

Odataframe.to_excel(excel_writer=excel_final, sheet_name='Sheet1', na_rep="")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create and `ExcelWriter` object:

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("path.xlsx")
dataframe.to_excel(excel_writer=writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', na_rep="")

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) is quite clear on how to use `df.to_excel()`.

It's enough to pass the path of your file.

```
Odataframe.to_excel(r'path.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', na_rep="")
```